# Assign type to an entity in Entity-Component System (super entity - syntactic sugar)

Tags: c++, entity-system

I have created ECS framework from scratch using C++.

Everything works fine, but I think my code is not so cute (at `#1`):-

```
class RocketComponent{
    Entity mainBodyGraphic;   
    Entity topGraphic ;
};
//inside some system (script-like)
void createRocket(){
    Entity mainBodyGraphic = graphicFactory->createCylinder();    
    Entity topGraphic = graphicFactory->createCone();    
    //^ internally create entity (with graphic component and others),
    //         then attach together
    Pointer<RocketComponent> rocket  = create<RocketComponent>();
    rocket->mainBodyGraphic = mainBodyGraphic;
    rocket->topGraphic = topGraphic;
    //.... other logics ....
}

void showDamage(Entity rocket){
     Pointer<RocketComponent> rocket  = rocket->get<RocketComponent>();
     systemGraphic->setColor(rocket->mainBodyGraphic,RED);   //#1
}
```

`#1` is ugly.
In my dream (Object-oriented style), `#1` could be :-

```
rocket->mainBodyGraphic->setColor(RED);                      //#1
```

The above line is far easier to read and code.     It is also less error-prone.

### The Change (super entity)

I plan to change my code to support it, but I don't want to lose any disadvantage of ECS.
Therefore, I will create **super entity**.

For example:-

- I create a new **super Entity** class named `GEntity` (graphic entity).
- I provide a converter (`operator=()`) between `Entity` and `GEntity`.
- Whenever a function just want `Entity`, I can pass `GEntity` instead, and vice versa!
- `graphicFactory->createCone()` and similar functions will return  `GEntity` instead of `Entity`.
- The field in `RocketComponent` will be `GEntity mainBodyGraphic;`.
- `Entity` has no access to game logic like before, but `GEntity` can access all game logic/system.

Here is my adoption (future plan / promise to myself):-

- In `GEntity`, I can add all syntactic sugar functions e.g. `setColor()` as much as I want.
- I will use `GEntity` only when logical type of entity is very obvious.
- I will also create `PEntity` = Physic body, because its type is also obvious.
- I may also create other types of **super entity** if its type is very obvious && I want the syntactic-sugar.

Here is the result (change marked with `$`):-

```
class RocketComponent{
    GEntity mainBodyGraphic;      //$
    GEntity topGraphic ;          //$ 
};
void createRocket(){
    GEntity mainBodyGraphic = graphicFactory->createCylinder(); //$ 
    GEntity topGraphic = graphicFactory->createCone();          //$ 
    Pointer<RocketComponent> rocket  = create<RocketComponent>();
    rocket->mainBodyGraphic = mainBodyGraphic;
    rocket->topGraphic = topGraphic;
    //.... other logics ....
}
void showDamage(Entity rocket){
     Pointer<RocketComponent> rocket  = rocket->get<RocketComponent>();
     rocket->mainBodyGraphic->setColor(RED);                    //$ 
}
```

### **Concern (my fear)**

I feel that I am violating some ECS rules.
I am probably destroying good ECS abstraction and design pattern in favor of my indolence.

I have already refactored some of my code to the new way.
It looks nice and neat.   I think I am biased.

### **Question**

- What are disadvantage of this approach?
- What are things (potential issue) that I should concern and prevent?
- What is the name of this technique/design-pattern (if any)?

Answer (score 1):

I would actually consider your rocket as a single entity.

That single entity holds a reference to a `MeshComponent` that is designed to hold a base mesh and zero or more sub meshes.  If we think about how meshes are separated to draw them with different materials, this is pretty common.  So that component would look like this:

```
struct mesh_t {
  string meshName;
  // other stuffs
};

struct MeshComponent {
  int entityId; 
  mesh_t baseMesh;
  vector<mesh_t> subMeshes;
};
```

The next question to ask is whether the graphics system's renderable representation should be exposed at all in your component.  I've seen some examples where developers do this:

```
struct MeshComponent {
  int entityId; 
  mesh_t baseMesh;
  vector<mesh_t> subMeshes;
  GraphicsRenderable* baseRenderable;
  vector<GraphicsRenderable*> subRenderables;
};
```

This works, but I prefer encapsulation and abstraction.  The `GraphicsRenderable` is the graphics system's scene graph representation of those meshes and I prefer that not to be immediately accessible by anyone who can get my `MeshComponent`.

Instead, the graphics system maintains an internal mapping between its scene graph *renderables* and the external `MeshComponent` instances.  The system knows when the component is destroyed, it has to cleanup the appropriate *renderables* or perhaps when state changes on the component, the system replicates those changes to the *renderables* internally.

So I end up with something like:

```
// external to ecs users

struct mesh_t {
  string meshName;
  // other stuffs
};

struct MeshComponent {
  int entityId; 
  mesh_t baseMesh;
  vector<mesh_t> subMeshes;
};

// internal to graphics system

struct Renderable {
  MeshComponent* component;
  vector3 position;
  vector4 rotation;
  scene_ptr node;
  ...
}
```

To specifically mention your use case about color, I would expose that on the `mesh_t` struct and your code becomes this to change it:

```
MeshComponent& mesh = entity.getComponent<MeshComponent>();
mesh.baseMesh.color = Colors.RED;
mesh.subMeshes[0].color = Colors.RED;
```

The next time the graphics system updates, it will replicate the color changes from the `MeshComponent` to the associated `Renderable` and then on the next draw, the meshes will be the color red.

At the end of the day, treat your ECS as a bridge between game code and base/core systems of your game engine.  Your game code interacts with components, systems take those interactions and manipulate internal models and structures to achieve the goal.

This separation of concerns will make refactoring code much easier too.